# How to deal with errors in loading saved torch model using stablebaseline3 library?

Tags: python-3.x, torch, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am trying to load a saved torch model using stablebaseline3  library but I get errors in loading state_dict which says network dimensions of check point and model do not match. Here I  print model architecture after saving as well as environment action and state spaces. Beside I tried to load model with and without giving environment and in both cases get errors. I have  python 3.11.4 , stable_baselines3 version 1.2.0 ,torch 2.0.1 and gym 0.25.2 installed. Here is my code:

`from stable_baselines3 import SAC`

```
model = SAC(
        policy="MlpPolicy",
        env=norm_env,
        batch_size=182,
        action_noise=None,
        learning_rate=0.0004,
        learning_starts=129,
        policy_kwargs={'net_arch': {'pi': [248, 303], 'qf': [377, 69]}},
        train_freq=15,
        tau=0.18,
        gamma=0.93,
        use_sde=True,
        use_sde_at_warmup=True,
        sde_sample_freq=7,
        gradient_steps=7,
        target_update_interval=13,
        verbose=0,)
model.save("SAC_BB_model.zip")
model = SAC.load(path="SAC_BB_model.zip", env=norm_env)
Action spaces do not match: Box(-100.0, 100.0, (4,), float32) != Box(-1.0, 1.0, (3,), float32)
model = SAC.load(path="SAC_BB_model.zip")

error occured while loading optuna_studies\SAC_BB_model.zip
Error(s) in loading state_dict for SACPolicy:
    size mismatch for actor.log_std: copying a param with shape torch.Size([303, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([303, 4]).
    size mismatch for actor.mu.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([3, 303]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([4, 303]).
    size mismatch for actor.mu.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([4]).
    size mismatch for critic.qf0.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([377, 7]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([377, 8]).
    size mismatch for critic.qf1.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([377, 7]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([377, 8]).
    size mismatch for critic_target.qf0.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([377, 7]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([377, 8]).
    size mismatch for critic_target.qf1.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([377, 7]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([377, 8]).
\stable_baselines3\common\save_util.py:166: 
UserWarning: Could not deserialize object action_space. Consider using `custom_objects` argument to replace this object.

print("norm_env observation space: " ,norm_env.observation_space)
print("norm_env action space: ", norm_env.action_space)
norm_env observation space:  Box(-100.0, 100.0, (4,), float32)
norm_env action space:  Box(-1.0, 1.0, (3,), float32)

print(model.actor)
Actor(
  (features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
    (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  )
  (latent_pi): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=4, out_features=248, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): Linear(in_features=248, out_features=303, bias=True)
    (3): ReLU()
  )
  (mu): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=303, out_features=3, bias=True)
    (1): Hardtanh(min_val=-2.0, max_val=2.0)
  )
)
print(model.critic)
ContinuousCritic(
  (features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
    (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  )
  (qf0): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=7, out_features=377, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): Linear(in_features=377, out_features=69, bias=True)
    (3): ReLU()
    (4): Linear(in_features=69, out_features=1, bias=True)
  )
  (qf1): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=7, out_features=377, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): Linear(in_features=377, out_features=69, bias=True)
    (3): ReLU()
    (4): Linear(in_features=69, out_features=1, bias=True)
  )
)
```